# Timing del operator on dictionaries, KeyError?

Tags: python, dictionary, timer, timeit, del

I've been working on a python assignment for a class I'm taking and I just can't figure out how to get past this KeyError. I'm trying to time the use of the del operator on dictionaries in python, here is my code:

```
from timeit import Timer


def build_dict(n): # build dict = { 0:"0", 1:"1", 2:"2", ... n:"n" }
    return {i : str(i) for i in range(n)}  

def dictionaryx(x,n):
    del x[0]
    del x[n//2]
    del x[n-1]

timeDict = Timer(
    "dictionaryx(x,n)",
    "from __main__ import n,build_dict,dictionaryx; x = build_dict(n)")


for size in range(1000, 100000+1, 5000):
    n = size
    dict_secs = timeDict.repeat(5,5)
    print(n, "\t", min(dict_secs))
```

Every time I try to run this code I get following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/mcastro/PycharmProjects/untitled1/testdel.py", line 21, in 
>       dict_secs = timeDict.repeat(5,5)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/timeit.py", line 206, in repeat
>       t = self.timeit(number)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/timeit.py", line 178, in timeit
>       timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
>     File "", line 6, in inner
>     File "/Users/mcastro/PycharmProjects/untitled1/testdel.py", line 10, in dictionaryx
>       del x[0]
>   KeyError: 0

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error or how to fix it, as far as I understand the keys the errors are referencing are present but can't be deleted? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `timeit` loop is using the same dictionary `x` every time.  The first time you call `dictionaryx(x,n)`, it deletes element 0 so it's not there the next time you call it.

```
def build_dict(n): # build dict = { 0:"0", 1:"1", 2:"2", ... n:"n" }
    return {i : str(i) for i in range(n)}

def dictionaryx(x,n):
    del x[0]
    del x[n//2]
    del x[n-1]

n = 1000
x = build_dict(n)
dictionaryx(x,n)    # this deletes x[0]
dictionaryx(x,n)    # this causes the error
```